# Cyrillic in Angular module QRCode

Tags: angularjs, qr-code

QRCode module https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode when entering Russian characters (Cyrillic). Displays in the QRCode wrong encoding.

Example:

"Привет мир" => "?@825B <8@"

Chain of transformations is obtained - 7-bit ASCII → KOI8-U + KOI8-R → ISO-8859-5

The file is saved in the encoding UTF-8, try other encodings, output -

???????

Demo example of the module is working properly. In what direction to search?

Sample code is as follows:

```
<div class="block-qr">
    <qrcode version="8" error-correction-level="Medium" size="400" data="{{vm.data}}" href="{{var}}" download></qrcode>
</div>
<form class="block-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Заголовок</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Заголовок" ng-model="vm.title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Организация</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Организация" ng-model="vm.org">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>Телефон</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" ng-model="vm.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="vm.emails">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Сайт</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Сайт" ng-model="vm.site">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.concat()">Сгенерировать</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function concat() {            
        vm.data = 'Title: ' + vm.title + '\nOrg: ' + vm.org + '\nPhone number: ' + vm.phone + '\nEmail: ' + vm.emails + '\n ' + vm.site;
      return vm.data;
    }
```

With Latin no problems, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to work with the Latin alphabet, you must connect the file 
http://monospaced.github.io/bower-qrcode-generator/js/qrcode_UTF8.js
When installing through bower, I did not notice that the Create 2 folders angular-qrcode and qrcode-generator. The file was in the second folder.